# Adding effects to a balanced XLR signal (microphone)

Tags: audio, single-supply-op-amp, balanced, xlr

I want to take a signal from a dynamic microphone (e.g. AKG D5), add a digital effect (echo using PT2399 chip), and then forward the signal to a male XLR connector and on through a standard XLR microphone cable to a mixer/PA.

However, I'm having problems turning the balanced XLR signal into a single-ended signal, for processing? I know the proper way to do it is to use a differential op amp, but I've also been told I can just connect pins 1 and 3, and just take pin 2 (the "hot" signal) through the FX circuit. However, doing this, I get no sound at all in the mixer.

[image]

**The above configuration does not seem to work.**

Connecting pins 1 and 3 only works if I *also* forward pins 1 and 3 through from input XLR to output XLR -- i.e. bypass the FX circuit.

[image]
[image]

**The above two configurations work.** I get an audible signal on the mixer, but it is a mix of (50/50?) "dry" and "wet" signal (dry = unprocessed mic, and wet = FX output). I want to be able to control this mix with a pot. Also, I don't understand why the first configuration is not working, to just connect pins 1 and 3 (i.e. ground pin 3) without "forwarding" the signal (as in the first drawing of the three above)? I read many places that this should be a possible way to handle this (without using a differential amplifier op amp). Am I misunderstanding the documentation on this?

**Footnote:**

Trying to understand why the signal just nulls out, I did this little thought experiment (below). Does this, to some extent, explain why I'm getting no sound (if I ground pin 3 on the FX output)?

As I understand it, the mixer performs common mode noise rejection, computing `noise = pin2 - inv(pin3)` followed by `signal = pin2 - noise`. So, if `pin3 = 0` (ground, flat line) then I guess `noise = pin2`, which should mean `signal = 0`... Is this why I get no signal, that I'm actually cancelling it out by grounding pin 3?

Comment: I've tried to compress the post into just dealing with the main question, of how to wire up XLR connectors such as to get an unbalanced signal (without using an actual differential op amp at the input). Reason I'm not doing a dif.amp is, simply, that the effects circuit will be very close to the source (mic) -- less than 5 cm -- so I believe I won't be needing common mode noise rejection on the input.

Comment: Why not use transformers to convert between single-sided and balanced line?  This minimises induced interference and will accept large common-mode voltage swings without problems.

Comment: You still have confusing remnants of your earlier rendition in paragraph 3. I think you need to be clearer about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: (For the record: Comments relating to the earlier version of this question have been deleted, as they are now obsolete and could cause confusion, since some parts of the question have been removed.)

Comment: @Andyaka Tried to go over the text once more. Thanks for taking an interest!

Comment: @Frog I'm aiming to make an effect circuit which clips onto the mic (with XLR connectors). My initial design omitted common mode rejection on the input, because no cable length would mean no (or negligible) noise picked up. However, if using a transformer (or diff op amp) would solve my signal problems I could surely incorporate an extra opamp on the input. I'm wondering if I need to also "restore" a balanced signal on the _output_, as at this point the signal will go through a (possibly long) XLR cable to the mixer, but that's sort of where this originally branched into multiple questions.

Comment: @joakimk from what you describe, balanced line on the output is more important than on the input, particularly since you won’t know how the next device downstream is configured.  It could conceivably have a transformer with a grounded centre tap on the primary (I haven’t looked at enough mixing desks to know if that’s a common configuration), but if it is then driving it from a single-sided source wouldn’t work well.

Comment: @joakimk my advice is to lose all the wet/dry stuff. Forget about the echo chip and concentrate on why you get signals and why you don't get signals. The wet/dry stuff is due the that chip and should be a separate question. You are conflating two different problems as if they are related. They are not.